# Prove there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)} = \frac{1}{a-c}+\frac{1}{b-c}.$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and positive for all $x \in(a,b).$ Prove that there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that 
$$\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)} = \frac{1}{a-c}+\frac{1}{b-c}.$$

This seems like just an application of the mean value theorem, but it doesn't seem to work out when I try.

My first attempt was to find an explicit equation for $f(x)$ since
$$f'(x) = f(x)\left( \frac{1}{a-x} + \frac{1}{b-x}  \right)\Rightarrow f(x) = e^{-\ln((a-x)(b-x)} \left( \frac{1}{a-x} + \frac{1}{b-x} \right)$$

But applying the mean value theorem doesn't quite work here because $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are not defined so $f(x)$ isn't continuous on $[a,b].$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f(x) \neq 0 \forall x \in (a,b)$ Prove $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118948/let-f-be-continuous-on-a-b-differentiable-on-a-b-and-fx-neq-0) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bf%27(c)%7D%7Bf(c)%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba-c%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb-c%7D.%24&p=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)=(x-a)(x-b)f(x)$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $g(a)=g(b)=0$. From Rolle's theorem there exists some $c\in (a,b)$ such that $g'(c)=0$ or

$$(c-b)f(c)+(c-a)f(c)+(c-a)(c-b)f'(c)=0$$

and this is equivalent with:

$$\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)} = \frac{1}{a-c}+\frac{1}{b-c}$$